# Backdrop filter not working when mix blend mode of another element on the page is changed

Tags: css-filters, mix-blend-mode

The browser version is Chrome 87.0.4280.88

Here is how I accidentally detected this bug:

> - There are two independent divs on the page and both are `position: fixed;`
> - One of them has a hover effect with which its `mix-blend-mode` is changed.
> - The other one has glassmorphism style on it with `backdrop-filter: blur(...px);`
> - The filter works only when the other element on the page is set to `mix-blend-mode: normal;` otherwise it looks like as if it was not supported.

I am going to quit using that hover effect for now anyway but if there is a trick then it would be nice to let the world know about it.

Answer (score 10):

Came across this bug as well (Chrome 90).

### Quick Fix:

Add any `backdrop-filter` rule to the same element that has the `mix-blend-mode` rule applied.

### Example:

```css
.blend {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  backdrop-filter: opacity(1); /* fixes the chrome-bug */
}
```

Comment: Worked for me (Chrome 91) when I added this to the parent of the mix-blend-mode element. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution also worked for me (Chrome 93). Although I've had to wrap my element inside another and apply the `mix-blend-mode` to it to make it work like so:

```css
.wrapper {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
    
.blend { 
  backdrop-filter: opacity(1);
}
```

Save me a lot of hours. Thanks a bunch!